# How do I select the highest value of one column and one of the repeats in a table using t-sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, subquery, repeat

I have a table with some of the data a test performs on different samples that have different desirability (P1 is better than S1 which is better than S3 which is better than S2) AND sometimes any of these tests could be repeated.  If a test fails, someone has to do it over.

I want my query to display only the best sample (P1>S1>S3>S2) AND only the repeated data, (not the original data).

The following query works but as you can see it is rather long and complicated.  I am still a junior SQL person so how can I accomplish the same thing with a shorter/better query ?

I am trying to learn better SQL so I do not always have to ask these types of questions so explanations of why your query works better would be very helpful !

```
   DECLARE @TempTable TABLE (Sample_ID varchar(10), TestRepeat int, TestResult varchar(1))
   --  In the end, ONLY the samples with Y should be displayed
   INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES('61-0001-P1', 0, 'R') -- 1  Y
   INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES('61-0002-P1', 0, 'R') -- 2  Y
   INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES('61-0003-S1', 0, 'S') -- 3  Y
   INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES('61-0004-S1', 0, 'R') -- 4  Y
   INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES('61-0005-P1', 0, 'I') -- 5 
   INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES('61-0005-P1', 1, 'S') -- 6  Y
   INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES('61-0006-P1', 0, 'S') -- 7  Y
   INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES('61-0006-S3', 0, 'R') -- 8
   INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES('61-0007-P1', 0, 'S') -- 9  Y
   INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES('61-0008-S3', 0, 'I') -- 10
   INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES('61-0008-S3', 1, 'R') -- 11 Y
   INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES('61-0009-P1', 0, 'R') -- 12 Y
   INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES('61-0009-S1', 0, 'S') -- 13
   INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES('61-0010-P1', 0, 'S') -- 14 Y
   INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES('61-0011-S3', 0, 'S') -- 15 Y

   DECLARE @TempTable1 TABLE (Subject_ID varchar(7), Sample_ID varchar(10), SampleOrder int, TestRepeat int, TestResult varchar(1))

   INSERT @TempTable1
   SELECT  LEFT(Sample_ID,7) AS Subject_ID, 
     Sample_ID,
     SampleOrder = 
       CASE 
         WHEN RIGHT(Sample_ID,2) = 'P1' THEN 4
         WHEN RIGHT(Sample_ID,2) = 'S1' THEN 3
         WHEN RIGHT(Sample_ID,2) = 'S3' THEN 2
         WHEN RIGHT(Sample_ID,2) = 'S2' THEN 1
       END, 
     TestRepeat, 
     TestResult
   FROM @TempTable
   ORDER BY Subject_ID, SampleOrder;

   --SELECT * FROM @TempTable1;

   DECLARE @TempTable2 TABLE (Sample_ID varchar(10), TestRepeat int, TestResult varchar(1))

   INSERT @TempTable2 SELECT 
     tt1.Sample_ID,
     tt1.TestRepeat,
     tt1.TestResult
    FROM @TempTable1 tt1
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT Subject_ID, MAX(SampleOrder) AS Max_SampleOrder
        FROM @TempTable1
        GROUP BY Subject_ID) subQ1 
        ON (tt1.Subject_ID=subQ1.Subject_ID AND tt1.SampleOrder=subQ1.Max_SampleOrder)
    ORDER BY tt1.Sample_ID;

   SELECT tt2.Sample_ID,
          tt2.TestRepeat, 
          tt2.TestResult
   FROM @TempTable2 tt2
   INNER JOIN (
        SELECT Sample_ID, MAX(TestRepeat) AS Max_TestRepeat
        FROM @TempTable2
        GROUP BY Sample_ID) subQ 
        ON (tt2.Sample_ID = subQ.Sample_ID AND tt2.TestRepeat=subq.Max_TestRepeat)
   ORDER BY tt2.Sample_ID, tt2.TestResult;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [row_number()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) in a sub query for this.

```
select Sample_ID, TestRepeat, TestResult
from
  (
    select Sample_ID, TestRepeat, TestResult,
           row_number() over(partition by left(Sample_ID, 7)
                             order by case right(Sample_ID,2)
                                        when 'P1' then 1
                                        when 'S1' then 2
                                        when 'S3' then 3
                                        when 'S2' then 4
                                       end, TestRepeat desc) as rn
    from @TempTable
  ) as T
where rn  = 1
order by Sample_ID
```

You can test the query on [SE-Data](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/66627)

Explanation:
`row_number` will enumerate your rows from `1`. The `partition by` clause controls when numbering start from `1` again and the `order by` clause specifies the order of the numbering. The `over()` clause used above will give you a `row_number()` of `1` for the rows you are interested in. It is not possible to use `row_number()` in the where clause of a query so you have to use a derived table to be able to filter your rows on the result of `row_number()`

Comment: An good understanding of Ranking functions can be found here : http://www.sqllion.com/2010/07/ranking-functions/

Answer (score 0):

Try using common table expressions.  You don't have to create all the table variables, it might be a little cleaner.  Here is an example, I kept the original table variable from your example for the source data.

```
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE (Sample_ID varchar(10), TestRepeat int, TestResult varchar(1))
--  In the end, ONLY the samples with Y should be displayed
INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES('61-0001-P1', 0, 'R') -- 1  Y
INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES('61-0002-P1', 0, 'R') -- 2  Y
INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES('61-0003-S1', 0, 'S') -- 3  Y
INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES('61-0004-S1', 0, 'R') -- 4  Y
INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES('61-0005-P1', 0, 'I') -- 5 
INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES('61-0005-P1', 1, 'S') -- 6  Y
INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES('61-0006-P1', 0, 'S') -- 7  Y
INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES('61-0006-S3', 0, 'R') -- 8
INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES('61-0007-P1', 0, 'S') -- 9  Y
INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES('61-0008-S3', 0, 'I') -- 10
INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES('61-0008-S3', 1, 'R') -- 11 Y
INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES('61-0009-P1', 0, 'R') -- 12 Y
INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES('61-0009-S1', 0, 'S') -- 13
INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES('61-0010-P1', 0, 'S') -- 14 Y
INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES('61-0011-S3', 0, 'S') -- 15 Y


;with CTE1 as 
(
    SELECT  LEFT(Sample_ID,7) AS Subject_ID, 
        Sample_ID,
        SampleOrder = 
        CASE 
            WHEN RIGHT(Sample_ID,2) = 'P1' THEN 4
            WHEN RIGHT(Sample_ID,2) = 'S1' THEN 3
            WHEN RIGHT(Sample_ID,2) = 'S3' THEN 2
            WHEN RIGHT(Sample_ID,2) = 'S2' THEN 1
        END, 
        TestRepeat, 
        TestResult
    FROM @TempTable
),
CTE2 as
(
SELECT 
        tt1.Sample_ID,
        tt1.TestRepeat,
        tt1.TestResult
    FROM CTE1 tt1
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT Subject_ID, MAX(SampleOrder) AS Max_SampleOrder
        FROM CTE1
        GROUP BY Subject_ID) subQ1 
        ON (tt1.Subject_ID=subQ1.Subject_ID AND tt1.SampleOrder=subQ1.Max_SampleOrder)
    ),
CTE3 as 
(
    SELECT tt2.Sample_ID,
            tt2.TestRepeat, 
            tt2.TestResult
    FROM CTE2 tt2
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT Sample_ID, MAX(TestRepeat) AS Max_TestRepeat
        FROM CTE2
        GROUP BY Sample_ID) subQ 
        ON (tt2.Sample_ID = subQ.Sample_ID AND tt2.TestRepeat=subq.Max_TestRepeat)
)
select * 
from CTE3;
```

It produces the same results as your example, without so many table variables. It should also be much more efficient that the table variables.

Here is a link to my blog with several examples of the Common Table Expressions.
http://stevestedman.com/category/classes/cte/

Hope this helps.  Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: You could probably do the same thing with subqueries, but that would be much more of a mess.